# route everything to index.php except one directory using FallbackResource

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes

I have used FallbackResource /index.php in htaccess to re-route every call to index.php

it works very fine and I am getting the result that I wanted, but I need one directory to access and that directory also re-routes to index.php. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FallbackResource` doesn't support exclusions like this. You can use `mod_rewrite` as an alternative.

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^exclude index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: This answer is just plain wrong, as far as I can see.

Comment: It worked for OP and it works in few rules that I am running on live website. You need to clarify `plain wrong` part, I guess.

Answer (score 5):

For disable routing fallback inside one directory use `disabled` keyord (Apache 2.4.4 and later).

```
  <Directory /var/www/path/to/disabled/dir>
        FallbackResource disabled
  </Directory>
```

In case of .htaccess files use `FallbackResource disabled` inside this dir.

Comment: This works perfectly, and is easy to generalize. Many websites can benefit from moving code from the htaccess file, where it cannot easily be debugged, to a PHP routing file.